# What does this mean? Binary number that represents number of inputs that are equal to 1?

Tags: boolean-logic, algebra, digital

I'm trying to create a truth table, but I don't understand what that phrase means? 
"Two ouputs must equal to the binary number that represents number of inputs that are equal to one"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is obscure, so let's think of the exercise as trying to create a truth table that somehow matches what we are told. In doing that we have to *interprete* each piece of information included in the phrase.

***Two outputs** must equal to the **binary number** that represents the **number of inputs that are equal to one***.

**Two outputs**

Given that every *output* in a truth table is one bit, I will interpret this as a truth table with two output columns. Let's call them `b1` and `b2` (`b` meaning `bit`)

**binary number**

Bits `b1` and `b2` will form a 2-digit binary number. So, possible results for the combined output are: `00`, `01`, `10` and `11`. These in turn respectively correspond to their decimal values `0`, `1`, `2` and `3`.

**inputs**

These are the first columns of our truth table. We don't know yet how many are they. But...

**number of inputs equal to one**

Given that the largest output value is `3` (see above), we can have at most `3` Boolean inputs. Lets call them `i1`, `i2` and `i3`.

**Combining all together**

```
i1  i2  i3  (sum) (binary) b1  b2
0   0   0     0      00     0   0
0   0   1     1      01     0   1
0   1   0     1      01     0   1
0   1   1     2      10     1   0
1   0   0     1      01     0   1
1   0   1     2      10     1   0
1   1   0     2      10     1   0
1   1   1     3      11     1   1
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much for the explanation! I really appreciate it. It makes total sense now :D